# Nginx – Multiple Sites one VPS - Correct Configuration?

Tags: nginx

I don’t really know anything about this but I’ve done a bit of reading. If I point my two domains to the VPS nameservers, and my app-nginx.conf looks like this:

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.domain1.com;
      root /path/to/your/project;
   }

server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.domain2.com;
      root /path/to/your/project;
   }
```

Is there anything else I would need to be doing? It doesn’t seem to work currently.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work saying what?

Comment: It says "Could Not Connect to Server". I can only access the server via IP.

Comment: If it is really "couldn't connect", then your name points to the wrong IP and it doesn't have much to do with nginx config.

Comment: So the nameserver values are wrong?

Comment: wrong, haven't propagated yet. Just see what your names resolve into and compare to ip address.

Comment: Would you mind telling me how to check where the domain is propogating to? I added the nameserver entries weeks ago.

Comment: You can try `host www.domain1.com` for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try on server:

```
telnet localhost 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.domain2.com
<double ENTER>
```

What you see now?

What you see in logs, when nginx start?
What is output of nginx -T ?